# RxJava onCompleted and onTerminate on main thread

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using RxJava with Retrofit 2.0 on Android for network requests.

When I'm creating the observable, I add the following to it:

```
observable = observable
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Then if I add a:

```
observable = observable.doOnTerminate(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    Log.d("OBS", "[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] onTerminate");
                }
            });
```

Or similar for `doOnError` and `doOnCompleted` the callbacks are executed on the IO thread, while `doOnNext` is executed on the main thread.

However, what I really want is for all callbacks to go to the main thread, but the execution should stay on the IO thread.

Is there an elegant solution to this without having to manually wrap my implementations with a block to post something to the main thread?

Comment: Use event buses and post to UI thread?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should place your callbacks before any `observeOn` so they'll stay on its previous thread:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.doOnTerminate(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()))
.map(v -> v + 1)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.map(v -> Thread.currentThread() + " / " + v)
.doOnNext(v -> Log.d("OBS", v))
.subscribe();
```